# If JOIN value is greater than X then set value to true

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT X(Coordinates) AS `latitude`, Y(Coordinates) AS `longitude`, `AtcoCode` AS `atcocode`, `CommonName` as `name`,
(
    SELECT COUNT(`jptl`.`id`)
    FROM `a`.`jps` `jptl`
    JOIN `a`.`journpat` `jp` ON `jp`.`journey_pattern_section_reference` = `jptl`.`journey_pattern_section_reference`
    JOIN `a`.`serv` ON `service`.`reference` = `jp`.`service_reference`
    JOIN `a`.`op` ON `operator`.`reference` = `service`.`operator_reference`
    JOIN `a`.`operator` `fmbo` ON fmbo.operator_reference = operator.reference
    WHERE `jptl`.`stop_from` = AtcoCode
) AS subscriber
FROM `a`.`qwerty`
WHERE MBRContains(
    GeomFromText( concat('LINESTRING(',50.922538,-1.301773,',',50.916856,-1.306708,')') ),
    Coordinates)
```

If the value of `subscriber` is greater than 1 then the `subscriber` value should be true, otherwise it should be false. How can I do this?

Comment: You have a database called 'a'?

Comment: @Strawberry Lol no I just changed it for the sake of the privacy of the company I'm working for X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IF`:

```
 ... as `name`, IF((... your query here) > 1, true, false) AS `subscriber`...
```

Check [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

Another option is modify your subquery, and compare `count(*)` with 1:

... SELECT COUNT(`jptl`.`id`) > 1 ...

But raw query will return 1 or 0, but it will be interpreted as `TRUE` or `FALSE` by most ORM's(if you use any)